# linux : find a lastname that has 5 characters only in a text

Tags: text-processing

Name, lastname, phone number .This is the text  :

```
Hace, Apoio, 703-2101 
Yoliot, Apostolos, 4222-1124
 Jenny,Thano,105-4122 
 Heriom,Koun, 510-4122 
 Dekon, Atolo, 502-2522 
 Feow, R,685-3431
```

I want to find all lastnames that have 5 characters only

**Edit:** I tried

```
egrep -i '[^:]+[a-z]5$' file2
```

but that doesn't work

Comment: What have you tried so far. Post relevant code pls. Also the is there a fixed formatting for your input. I can see commas with spaces and commas without spaces.?

Comment: What determines where a name ends and a lastname starts? A comma followed by a space?  A dash?  A comma? Is whitespace significant or should it be ignored?

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*,[[:blank:]]*' 'length($2) == 5'
```

Sets the field separator to `,` optionally surrounded by blanks and reports lines whose second field has a length of 5.

With `grep`:

```
grep -E '^[^,]*,[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:],][^,]{3}[^[:blank:],][[:blank:]]*(,|$)'
```

However note that `[^,]` and `[^[:blank:],]`, match *collating elements*, which depending on the locale are not necessarily single characters. For instance, in a Czech locale on a GNU system, that would match on:

```
Stéphane,Chazel,555-5555
```

Because `Ch` is a collating element there. So it finds 5 collating elements between those two commas (`<Ch><a><z><e><l>`).

With GNU `grep`, you can use the `-P` option instead of `-E` to use PCREs where bracket expressions only match characters.

They won't match sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters. That can be a concern if the file has characters written in a character set different from the one in the current locale. For instance it won't match on

```
Stéphane,ABCDE,555-5555
```

If the current locale uses UTF-8 as the character set but that `é` was written in the iso-8859-1 character set (0xe9 byte), because then that `é` won't be matched by `[^,]` (as being an invalid byte sequence, it's not one of the *collating elements other than `,`*).

Also note that some graphemes can be represented by more than one character in UTF-8 locales. For instance, `é` above can be represented by the U+00E9 character but also by the U+0065 character (`e`) followed by U+0301 (combining acute accent).

To match on graphemes/glyphs, you can use `-P` again and the `\X` operator that matches on grapheme clusters:

```
grep -P '^[^,]*,\h*(?![\h,])\X((?!,)\X){3}(?![\h,])\X\h*(,|$)'
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using "egrep" with \s and \S tokens

```
egrep '^[^,]*,\s*\S{5},' file
```

- Skip first field including first comma,
- skip whitespace after first comma,
- then match 5 letters followed by optional whitespace and a comma

Comment: Note that `\s` and `\S` are GNU specific. The standard equivalent (for `grep -E` the standard equivalent of `egrep`) are `[[:space:]]` and `[^[:space:]]` (`[:space:]` being `[:blank:]` plus some additional vertical space character like form feed, carriage return, vertical tab, line/paragraph separator..). Like their standard equivalent, they match collating elements which may be made of more than one character.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine 3 tools:

```
cut -d "," -f2 file | tr -d " " | grep -E "^.{5}$"
```