# only regular expressions : i want the lastnames that start with A or R

Tags: regular-expression

```
name ,lastname,phonenumber
Hace, Apoio, 703-2101 
Yoliot, Apostolos, 4222-1124
Jenny,Thano,105-4122 
Aeriom,Koun, 510-4122 
Dekon, Atolo, 502-2522 
Feow, R,685-3431
```

I did this but doesnt worked and I have no idea how it can be :  [A|R]

Comment: Please stop creating new accounts and posting the same question! As I told you before, you have created multiple users with the same name ([1](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/167618/e-op),[2](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/167620/e-op), [3](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/167619/e-op)), that's why you can't edit the post. Either log in as the original or see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep '^[^,]*,\s*[AR]\S{4},' file
```

See my answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279189/162960 for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `^[AR]` .
It means weather start with A or R by using `grep` command.